# VSCode - adding c# assembly reference

Tags: visual-studio-code

Getting the following error:

> The name 'File' does not exist in the current context[dnxcore50]

Tried to build it in-case it was to do with VSCode alone. It threw me same error.
I have installed the dependency using the following:

```
dnu install System.IO
```

Gave me the following message

> c:\Users\user1\Dropbox\dev\csharp\vscode\ads\WeightedGraphs>dnu
>   install System.IO
>       GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='System.IO'.
>       OK https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='System.IO' 679ms
>       System.IO.4.0.10-beta-22816 was added to project.json.
>       Restoring packages for c:\Users\user1\Dropbox\dev\csharp\vscode\ads\WeightedGraphs\project.json
>       Writing lock file c:\Users\user1\Dropbox\dev\csharp\vscode\ads\WeightedGraphs\project.lock.json
>       Restore complete, 302ms elapsed

project.json

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
        "System.IO": "4.0.10-beta-22816"
    },
    "commands": {
        "run": "run"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": {},
        "dnxcore50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-22816",
                "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-22816",
                "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-22816"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In.cs

```
using System.IO;
public class In{
    public In(string s){
        var filename = s;
        var path = "";
        if(File.Exists(path)){  
            //Code TO Be Added
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to add "System.IO.FileSystem" to your dependencies.

Comment: thank you, that fixed the problem. How ever curiour, how should i know

Comment: looking into docs(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx), does not give me that info, neither do I add that dependency when i use Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, this is one of the oddities of .NET Core. As .NET Core is still a work in progress and much of its documentation has not been written yet. (http://dotnet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)